# Getting size of files in a directory

Tags: c, dirent.h

I trying to get size of files in a directory by using dirent.h headers. However

```
stat(ent->d_name, &statbuf)
```

returns always -1 and I can't get the size properly. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`d_name` contains the name of the file within that directory. `stat` wants a name including the directory part, unless it's the current directory.

Make a temporary string containing the full path to the `d_name` file.

EDIT: Sample

```
char const * DirName = "/tmp";
....
char * FullName = (char*) malloc(strlen(DirName) + strlen(ent->d_name) + 2); 
strcpy(FullName, DirName);
strcat(FullName, "/");
strcat(FullName, ent->d_name);
stat(FullName, &statbuf);
free(FullName);
```

Comment: After i gave directory name to the stat, it always returned 4096 per file.

Comment: thetux4: You need to give a string consisting of *directory* and *file* to stat. If you give just a directory name, you'll get the size of the directory, which typically starts at 4096

Answer (score 1):

I use C++ and I thought the above code would work, but it didn't because it still needed a conversion from void to char*:

```
char *fullName = (char*) malloc(strlen(path) + strlen(entry->d_name) + 2);
```

hopefully this can help someone :)